# how does flask handle simultaneous requests?

Tags: python, flask

my flask app does the following : user uploads file - file gets
processed -->flask returns file

I was curios what does happen if two users simultaneous access the website and perform the same task.

I used [selenium server](https://www.selenium.dev/) in combination with [ray](https://github.com/ray-project) to perform a simultaneous request on the app

code in short form

```
ray.init()

@ray.remote
def parallel_1():
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
        desired_capabilities={
            "browserName": "chrome",
        })

# do task


ret_id1 = parallel_1.remote()
ret_id2 = parallel_1.remote()
ret1, ret2 = ray.get([ret_id1, ret_id2])
```

the flask view functions are plane simple no threads or sessions,
is there something going on under the hood what Im not aware off ? or how does flask handle simultaneous requests ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flask doesn't. Parallel request handling is the task of the underlying WSGI web server, which sends the requests to Flask for handling.

Flask's built-in development server which is invoked with [`Flask.run()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/server/) runs with threads by default

In production, you'd use one of the [WSGI containers or other deployment options](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/), and you control parallelism there. [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/), for example, has the [`-w` command line argument](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#commonly-used-arguments) which controls the number of worker processes, and [`-k`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class) which controls how these workers work (processes, threads, or a Tornado event machine, among others).